# Jquery: create footnotes popover

Tags: jquery, footnotes

Since from some days i'm trying to figure out how to implement a popover for footnotes in some on line pages.
Me and some friends are developing a new website with octoberCMS, an amazing cms built on top of laravel.

We have generated a ton of pages, chapters from a book, and imported in html to our site. We used this [script](https://github.com/oazabir/GoogleDoc2Html) to transfrom file from doc to html, and with some modifies works like a charm.

But we have formatted the footnotes: like this `<a class="footnote" href="#footnote1">(1)</a>` without using the `<sup>` tag.

I tried to use [bigfoot.js](https://github.com/lemonmade/bigfoot) to achive my task without success, also trying to set the params i can't intercept correct html in the dom.

These are the differences:
bigfoot.js format

```
<sup id="fnref:1"><a href="#fn:1" rel="footnote">(1)</a></sup>
<div class="footnotes">
    <ol>
      <li class="footnote" id="fn:1">
          <p>Cake topping jelly-o caramels.<a href="#fnref:1" title="return to article"> ↩</a><p>
      </li>
```

My format

```
<a class="footnote" href="#footnote1">(1)</a>
<h2>Notes</h2>
<p class="footnoteContent" id="footnote1">
```

Now i don't know which way to follow:
Try to change my markup via find and replace with notepad++. But can't figure out how to automatic change all my reference from  `<a class="footnote" href="#footnote1">(1)</a>` to `<sup id="fnref:1"><a href="#fn:1" rel="footnote">(1)</a></sup>`

Or using a jquery function to intercept all a with class footnote and append them to a popover. Using, for example, the bootstrap built-in popover function or something similar.

Have suggestions?

Bye